# Unselect on normal click - IE doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have a bunch of  elements that needs to be able to unselect on click (without CTRL+Click, because users are dumb and won't figure it out without intensive training, lol)

I have the following code, works brilliantly in Chrome/Firefox, not in IE 11 (don't have earlier versions to test on yet):

```
$('[id^=sel_]').on('mousedown', 'option', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    if ($(this).is(':selected')) {
        $(this).prop("selected", false);
    } else {
        $(this).prop("selected", true);
    }

    $(this).change();

    return false;
});
```

As you can see it's pretty simple, everything with an ID that starts with "sel_" should get a "mousedown" event on their options. If the option is selected, unselect. If the option is not selected, select.

I've tried "mouseup" and different iterations of the same function. IE entirely ignores it for some reason. I've read elsewhere on Stack (for checkboxes) that it doesn't work in IE, but jQuery's documenation states it does work for all versions of IE that they support.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/576A5/

Comment: Can you provide a simple demo on jsfiddle?

Comment: Ommit the 'option' parameter in the event binding, you already bind it to a given group of elements based on their id.

Comment: If I ommit the 'option' parameter, the mouse down fires, but it doesn't select or unselect an option at all. I tried that already

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry but, the issue depends of specific implementation of `select` element native to each browser. IE handles it in a different way and it's making your workaround broke.

I think a solution can be to implement your own custom `select` control or use a ready plugin for that (like [`chosen`](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)).

Using a stable plugin will help you to handle mobile devices/tablets, that with a custom control need particolar attention.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't accept this answer at all. If it's so broken, why does jQuery say it works? If it's so broken, why does a plugin like chosen apparently work? I'm a programmer. I don't want to bloat my software any more than it should be by adding plugins adding functionality I'll never need, that I could have a few lines of code do for me

Comment: Is not a jQuery issue, it's a IE browser UI choice and event handling. I know you are a programmer but some other developers tried to handle it. The only full working and cross browser solution is to mimic a standard select element with a plugin or a custom control (side note chosen in not heavy at run time)

Comment: It seems that clicking an option element in IE11 always unselects it at first, just to select it a fraction of a second later. Doesn't make sense but seems Irvin could be right about this.

Answer (score -1):

1) Use `$('[id^="sel_"]')`

2) Use `.attr("selected", true);` (instead of prop)

3) Ommit the `'option'` parameter in the event binding

Note: is the mouse event fired at all? (use console.log)

Comment: 1) The selector isn't the issue. It works if I take out the "option" bit so it acts on the entire select. IE ignores it when I specify "run on option" as my code above. 2) It doesn't matter if prop or attr is used, they never get fired

Comment: Ok so it's an event issue, thanks for clearing that up. There is a difference between prop and attr though, but this is outside the scope of this question. I'll await a jsfiddle as requested by Irvin.

Comment: I tried 3) before even asking this question. How about editing the jsFiddle and trying it yourself? You'll see if doesn't work

Comment: I see what you mean now, there seems to be no easy way to disable the native click event for select options in IE11